# What's the purpose of numpys argmax used with a scalar?

Tags: python, numpy

Recently I used the numpy `argmax` function which gives the index of the maximum value in a numpy array.
Due to some circumstances I found out that when used with a scalar it just gives out 0, so like this:

```
np.argmax(3) # equals 0
np.argmax(1000) #equals 0
```

which makes sense of course, since there is only one index - but is there an actual application where one needs to find the maximum index of a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just for consistency as explained in the documentation on [scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html):

> Array scalars have the same attributes and methods as ndarrays. This
> allows one to treat items of an array partly on the same footing as
> arrays, smoothing out rough edges that result when mixing scalar and
> array operations.

When you don't specify `axis` in `argmax` it returns the index into the flattened array, so even in this case the scalar is internally viewed as a 0D array.